# Parsing names in mixed formats using R

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

I have a list of names in mixed formats, which I would like to separate into columns containing first and last names in R.  An example dataset:

```
Names <- c("Mary Smith","Hernandez, Maria","Bonds, Ed","Michael Jones")
```

The goal is to assemble a dataframe that contains names in a format like this:

```
FirstNames <- c("Mary","Maria","Ed","Michael")
LastNames <- c("Smith","Hernandez","Bonds","Jones")
FinalData <- data.frame (FirstNames, LastNames)
```

I tried a few approaches to select either the First or Last name based on whether the names are separated by a space only versus comma-space.  For instance I wanted to use regular expressions in gsub to copy first names from rows in which a comma-space separates the names:

```
FirstNames2 <- gsub (".*,\\s","",Names)
```

This worked for rows that contained names in the *LastName, FirstName* format, but gsub collected the entire contents in rows with names in *FirstName LastName* format.

So my request for help is to please advise: How would you tackle this problem?  Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: are names with commas _always_ in "LastName, FirstName" format? or can they switch?

Comment: In my list, they are always in LastName, FirstName format.  However, it might help others if we could figure out a way to handle both variations.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a one-liner. The pattern tries *Firstname lastname* first and if that fails it tries *lastname, firstname*. No packages are used.

```
read.table(text = sub("(\\w+) (\\w+)|(\\w+), (\\w+)", "\\1\\4 \\2\\3", Names), as.is=TRUE)
```

giving:

```
       V1        V2
1    Mary     Smith
2   Maria Hernandez
3      Ed     Bonds
4 Michael     Jones
```

Comment: OK so what I learned from this and the answer by drmariod is the use of escaped numbers to indicate "captured" groups in a regex.  Correct?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, "\\1", "\\2", etc. are backreferences and (...) are capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

You could rearrange the , version to first last name and then just `strsplit`.

```
FirstNames <- sapply(strsplit(gsub('(\\w+), (\\w+)', '\\2 \\1', Names), ' '), `[[`, 1)
LastNames <- sapply(strsplit(gsub('(\\w+), (\\w+)', '\\2 \\1', Names), ' '), `[[`, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = strsplit(x = Names, split = "(, | )")
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(temp), function(i){
    if (grepl(pattern = ", ", x = Names[i])){
        data.frame(F = temp[[i]][2], L = temp[[i]][1])
    }else{
        data.frame(F = temp[[i]][1], L = temp[[i]][2])
    }
}))
#        F         L
#1    Mary     Smith
#2   Maria Hernandez
#3      Ed     Bonds
#4 Michael     Jones
```